# A Curious sum of sines and cosines with angles in arithmetic progression

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I am stuck with the following problem:
\begin{align}
\max_{\theta\in\mathbb{R}}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(a_i\sin(i\theta)+b_i\cos(i\theta)),
\end{align}
where for $i(1\leq i\leq N$)$, a_i$ and $b_i$ are real numbers. If a solution is not known, please point to references which deals with this sort of equations.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Answer (score 1):

This is a trigonometric polynomial, or a finite instance of a Fourier series with period $2\pi$. There is nothing obvious that would help you to find the maximum, take the first derivative and look for its roots.

Comment: Also: it is periodic, so you only have to look in $[0,2\pi]$ for the maximum.